# How to assist screen reader users to quickly iterate through results on the page without hiding additional information from the page?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I am looking for a way to markup a page in HTML to allow screen reader users to iterate through search results more quickly.

The design where only small information extracts are present and additional information is hidden using a collapsible element was rejected as it limits sighted users' experience.

I am now considering using headers to allow assistive technology users to quickly skip between the content blocks:

```
        <h2>Search results</h2>
        <div>
            <h3>Result 1 title</h3>
            <!–– some other longer information ––>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Result 2 title</h3>
            <!–– some other longer information ––>
        </div>
           <!–– more search results ––>
```

Is this technique appropriate? Websites, such as Google, do it when returning search results. However, [some sources](https://usability.yale.edu/web-accessibility/articles/headings#using) warn against overusing headings.

Comment: I don't think this is overusing. Some screen reader users like to iterate over a type of elements on a page, for example over headings. If Google does it, and they have dedicated accessibility specialists, I'd do what they do.

Comment: Yes. Using headings are appropriate for this use-case. I'd also recommend putting the link to the result location inside of the h3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headings are one option, however as these are search results why not make them links instead?

The beauty of this is that it allows users to quickly and easily jump between sections (as screen reader users will use shortcuts to skip between links) and also benefits your non screen reader users.

Also for semantics and to provide extra information you should put each result within a `<li>` as part of an ordered list `<ul>`

This has the added benefit of announcing how many items there are within the list and is good practice.

So your results page would then look like the following:

```
<h2>Search results</h2>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="results1">Result 1 title</a>
        <!–– some other longer information ––>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="results1">Result 1 title</a>
        <!–– some other longer information ––>
    </li>
       <!–– more search results ––>
</ul>
```

It also stops bad practices such as adding 'read more' links after each item and when a user is skipping through the links the link text will make sense.

Comment: Thank you, @Graham - deeper understanding of how do AT users interact with web pages (like using shortcuts to skip between links) is exactly what I was looking for! We already use links on the results page - I was just simplifying my example. :)